# Custom DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I ve been stuck on a DatePicker problem for several and i can't seem to find any solution.

I currently have a DatePickerDialog which fits quite well to my needs YET I also need to be able to hide / disable Both Day and Month field (in order to select a Month or a Year), I can't find any solution except implementing my own MonthPicker/yearPicker . the fact is I don't really know where to begin with to write a picker which has the same style as the default one.

I would be glad if any of you have sample code of custom date picjer or any simpler Idea to get to cope with my problem.

Thanks a lot

hush

Comment: Try this,You can start from here, It has normal spinner selection and complex view pager swipe http://viswanathl.in/2014/02/custom-datepicker-in-android/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My idea is using a custom Date Picker for android. In Google Code, I found an open source project called [Android Wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

[image: Android wheel for date time picker]

After checkout source code from Google Code, you'll find several example so that you can easily customize a year-picker as you want.

Comment: @Nikita You can find in my answer the link to his Google Code repo.

Comment: can you give me the link please ?

Comment: i can't find any source or sample there

Comment: Hi, i too want to know how to use wheel date picker..But the link contains only images..where can we find the source code??

Answer (score 3):

There is some change in honeycomb.

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.picker);
group = (ViewGroup) group.getChildAt(0);
group = (ViewGroup) group.getChildAt(0);
// 0:datepicker , 1:calendar
Toast.makeText(this, String.format("%s children", group.getChildCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
try{
    group.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // 0 for year, 1 for month, 2 for day
}catch(Exception e){
Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its kinda hacky, but if you look at the layout for the DatePicker you can see its a FrameLayout containing 3 sub-views.  So I was wanting the hide the year and did this.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.picker);
    group = (ViewGroup) group.getChildAt(0);
    Toast.makeText(this, String.format("%s children", group.getChildCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try{
        group.getChildAt(2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // 2 for year, 1 for day, 0 for month
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This gets the framelayout of the picker and then hides its 3rd child which is the year.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Though only the year could be hidden successfully in general, as month and day position depends on locale (month/day/year for US and day/month/year for UK for example).